# g++ compiler running error “g++: error: spawn: Exec format error”

Tags: c++, linux, g++, cygwin, cross-platform

I've wrote a C++ program in Linux & i used Linux headers like `unistd.h` in it.
now i have to compile it for Windows & i used `Cygwin with g++`.

but as it's clear in [image: ***this picture***], it compiles one time & when i compile again after that, it errors "*`g++: error: spawn: Exec format error`*"

why this happens & what should i do for fixing it?

ps: `g++ myfile.cpp -v` output:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/git/cygwin-ports-gcc/gcc-4.7.3-1/src/gcc-4.7.3/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/git/cygwin-ports-gcc/gcc-4.7.3-1/src/gcc-4.7.3 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/lib --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --disable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-ppl --with-system-zlib : (reconfigured) /cygdrive/i/szsz/git/cygwin-ports-gcc/gcc-4.7.3-1/src/gcc-4.7.3/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/git/cygwin-ports-gcc/gcc-4.7.3-1/src/gcc-4.7.3 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdir=/usr/lib --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --datarootdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --disable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-ppl --with-system-zlib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -D__CYGWIN32__ -D__CYGWIN__ -Dunix -D__unix__ -D__unix -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/../../../../include/w32api -idirafter ../../include/w32api tro_client.cpp -quiet -dumpbase tro_client.cpp -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase tro_client -version -o /tmp/ccDDULRP.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.7.3 (i686-pc-cygwin)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.7.3, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.0.1-p4, MPC version 1.0.1
warning: MPFR header version 3.0.1-p4 differs from library version 3.1.2.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=47 --param ggc-min-heapsize=32696
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "../../include/w32api"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/i686-pc-cygwin
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include-fixed
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/../../../../include/w32api
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.7.3 (i686-pc-cygwin)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.7.3, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.0.1-p4, MPC version 1.0.1
warning: MPFR header version 3.0.1-p4 differs from library version 3.1.2.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=47 --param ggc-min-heapsize=32696
Compiler executable checksum: 32d481c3b6460a57b566c5b2698c9e31
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/as.exe -v -o /tmp/cc0pZbht.o /tmp/ccDDULRP.s
g++: error: spawn: Exec format error
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [g++ compiler error "g++: error: spawn: Exec format error"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366957/g-compiler-error-g-error-spawn-exec-format-error)

Comment: yes you right, sorry i'm the author of both, i'm a newbie in here & i could not edit the other. (i think it's because it was on hold .) i think this is more clear than the other.

Comment: OK, i think i've deleted that !

Comment: What libraries are you linking with (if any)?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to run an executable that was built for another architecture or that uses a different binary format. You couldn't perhaps be running a Linux executable on your Windows (cygwin) system, could you?

Comment: @ 0x499602D2. I am not using any libraries.

Comment: @Steve.                                                                If it's for another architecture, so why it runs one time correctly ?

Comment: add `-v` to your command line. This will cause g++ to output more detailed information. Post that here.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the same problem today - and came up with kind of an esoteric solution that I'm about to add for reference here.

The problem in my case is, that the compiler tool-chain - a 64-bit cygwin gcc - has to be checked to a revision control system. Unfortunately this RCS not only messes with line endings but also removes file attributes. In my case the `S` (System) file attribute was missing for the file `as.exe` (in my case located in the aarch64-unknown-elf folder).

Initially the `S` attribute was not set for `as.exe`:

```
C:\gccInstallDir\arm\v8hf\aarch64-unknown-elf\bin>attrib as.exe
A            C:\gccInstallDir\arm\v8hf\aarch64-unknown-elf\bin\as.exe
```

and when trying to compile on Windows 7 64-Bit I get:

```
arm_v8hf-gcc: error: spawn: Exec format error
```

But with the attribute set:

```
C:\gccInstallDir\arm\v8hf\aarch64-unknown-elf\bin>attrib +S as.exe
C:\gccInstallDir\arm\v8hf\aarch64-unknown-elf\bin>attrib as.exe
A  S         C:\gccInstallDir\arm\v8hf\aarch64-unknown-elf\bin\as.exe
```

The compilation works fine!

I have no clue why the `as.exe` needs to be a system file, but when I try to call the `as.exe` from command line I get a message stating that `as.exe` is not compatible with the current windows version.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Those files are internally symlinks, and apparently cygwin uses the "S[ystem]" attribute to denote symlinks on Windows! Or, maybe, it's just me.